# Trying to Write a Short Photo Caption and Description

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

I am trying to translate this caption and description. However, I am not entirely sure if my translation is correct.

Caption: "When I was in San Francisco's Chinatown"
Translation: 当我在旧金山的唐人街

Description: Last year, my cousin and I went to San Francisco's Chinatown. We ate Chinese food and drank boba milk tea. It was a great day!
Translation: 去年我和我表姐一起去了旧金山的唐人街。我们吃了中国早餐，也喝了波霸奶茶。那天真不错！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did very well translating it.

Some minor suggestion:

> *"Caption: When I was in San Francisco's Chinatown" Translation: 当我在旧金山的唐人街*

"When" indicates 'time', therefore, your translation should be 
"当我在旧金山唐人街的时候" (you can omit 当)

> *Description: Last year, my cousin and I went to San Francisco's Chinatown. We ate Chinese food and drank boba milk tea. It was a great day! Translation: 去年我和我表姐一起去了旧金山的唐人街。我们吃了中国早餐，也喝了波霸奶茶。那天真不错！*

"去年我和表姐一起去了旧金山的唐人街。我们在那里吃了中式早餐，还喝了波霸奶茶。真是不错的一天！"

- the second 我 in 去年我和我表姐 can be omitted
- 我们(在那里)吃了中式早餐
- I suggest using **还**(also) instead of 也(also/ too) in  "吃了中式早餐，还喝了波霸奶茶"。to indicate Boba milk tea is in addition of having Chinese breakfast (which is the main event).
- 中国早餐  could mean "breakfast from China",  you should use **中式**早餐  (Chinese breakfast) here, because you are in Chinatown, not in China
- 那天真不错！(sound too matter of fact, the day was good, but how good?) --> 真是愉快的一天！(describe your feeling about that specific day)